# How to Structure Data Under Saved Data in Firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code in Firebase.

```
//Create a reference to a Firebase database URL
Firebase *savedRef2 = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://example.firebaseio.com/Location_Coordinates"];

// Write data to Firebase

Firebase *postRef2 = [savedRef2 childByAppendingPath: @"LOCATION DATA"];
NSDictionary *post1 = @{
                      @"DATE":  dateString,
                      @"Lat": @(location.coordinate.latitude),
                      @"Long": @(location.coordinate.longitude),
                      @"USER": name,
                      };
Firebase *post1Ref = [postRef2 childByAutoId];
[post1Ref setValue: post1];
```

When a user clicks save on the app, the data is saved to my Firebase data base but it keeps saving as a new object right under the previous saved. How can I make it so it saves once and the rest that are saved are childs of that first saved data?

This is a picture [Current saved data for coordinates.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTTRo.png) of how it keeps saving and I don't want it like this. How can I make it so it looks like this [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIlZE.png). I am saving coordinates of users but it keeps recreating a new 'childByAutoId' string and I just want the saved data to fall under the 1st 'childByAutoId' string and not to keep creating new ID's so each users coordinates fall under one ID each time it is saved.

**UPDATE:**
I have different users submitting data and in that data are coordinates. I want that same users data to be created ONLY under ONE node using 'childByAutoID' and the rest of the data (coordinates) will be under that. The way it is set up right now is that MULTIPLE nodes (childByAutoId) are being logged to Firebase and it makes it hard for me to read it so that is why I want ONE node (childByAutoId) created first and the rest fall under that EACH time someone clicks save.
This is how I currently have it. [image: Current] And this is how I want it [image: Want]

Comment: ChildByAutoId creates a new node name. So the code will create separate child nodes under LOCATION DATA each time [post1 setValue:post1] is called. It appears the two images you linked are actually the same - if you click the minus sign next to each node name in Current Saved image, it will be like the one in image 2. So... the code appears to be working - can you clarify the issue?

Comment: I just want 1 new node to be created and then the rest of the data to fall under that node. How can I make it so only 1 node is created and the rest of them fall as child nodes to that specific new node? @Jay

Comment: @CarlosAlan In the question you wrote that you want new created nodes to be children of the first created one - is it really what you want to achieve? In addition, both your structures looks the same to me, and the code you provided creates exactly the structure from picture 2

Comment: I have different users submitting data and in that data are coordinates. I want that same users data to be created ONLY under ONE node using 'childByAutoID' and the rest of the data (coordinates) will be under that. The way it is set up right now is that MULTIPLE nodes (childByAutoId) are being logged to Firebase and it makes it hard for me to read it so that is why I want ONE node (childByAutoId) created first and the rest fall under that EACH time someone clicks save. @pkacprzak

Comment: I updated this post with new pictures of how it currently is and how I want it. (I photoshopped the second picture of how I want it structured so it could be visual instead of me trying to type it). @Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super easy!

When a user authenticates the auth Firebase variable is populated with their user id.

In general if you are storing information about users you would store that data or associate that data with their uid.

So, when you want to store data for each user, store it in a node where the parent is their uid

```
Location_Coordinates
 LOCATION DATA
   uid_0
     childByAutoId
     childByAutoId
   uid_1
     childByAutoId
     childByAutoId
```

then to create the reference

```
Firebase *rootRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://example.firebaseio.com];
Firebase *locCoordsRef = [rootRef childByAppendingPath("Location_Coordinates");
Firebase *locDataRef = [locCoordsRef childByAppendingPath("LOCATION DATA"];

NSString *uid = rootRef.authData.uid

Firebase *thisUserRef = [locDataRef childByAppendingPath(uid)];

NSDictionary *userDataDict = @{
                      @"DATE":  dateString,
                      @"Lat": @(location.coordinate.latitude),
                      @"Long": @(location.coordinate.longitude),
                      @"USER": name,
                      };
Firebase *dataRef = [thisUserRef childByAutoId];
[dataRef setValue: userDataDict];
```